# How to make a POST call in SOAP UI to Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, soapui

I have these things at hand, but not able to create the POST request for amazon dynamo using soap ui.

-Resource url
-ARN
-API key with write permission
-Gateway route.

Please suggest how do I do. I am able to do GET call from SOAP UI. POST is throwing a 'Missing Authentication Token' error. I have an api key what should be the parameter name for the key? I tried accessKey, api_key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is the best tool to perform this task.

[Postman to test the api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html)

[Detailed documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html#call-api-with-api-gateway-custom-authorization)

Basically, you need to set the `Auth` in the header. You can try this on SOAPUI.

**Key :** Auth

**Value :** allow

**Screenshot:-**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I set the Auth to 'No Authorization' and added header attributes. Also it didn't work with SOAPUI, I had to download SOAPUI NG and also it worked fine with POSTMAN.